# FFMPEG - aws console issue

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, aws-lambda

I have created aws lambda function and run on aws console but got an error

```
Error: spawn EACCES
at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:323:11)
at exports.spawn (child_process.js:502:9)
at Timeout.setTimeout [as _onTimeout] (/var/task/handler.js:23:22)
at ontimeout (timers.js:482:11)
at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:317:5)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:277:5)
```

I have set alrady  process.env['PATH'] like below this

```
 process.env['PATH'] = process.env['PATH'] + ':/tmp/:'  +
 process.env['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT'] +
 ':' + process.env['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT'] + '/bin' +
 ':' + process.env['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT'] + '/lib';
```

i am using ffmpeg binary which is available in bin folder so i want to access ffmpeg on aws linux machine.
my code folder structure like

[image]

Comment: FWIW, there's https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg-static

Comment: now i got error  Error: { Error: spawn /var/task/node_modules/ffmpeg-binaries/bin/ffmpeg ENOENT

Comment: The thing I linked is `ffmpeg-static`, not `ffmpeg-binaries`. I'm not familiar with the latter.

Comment: I am using ffmpeg-binaries and test on aws console where i got this Error: { Error: spawn /var/task/node_modules/ffmpeg-binaries/bin/ffmpeg ENOENT any one know solution of this error please help me

Comment: I don't use ffmpeg-binaries so I can't help you with it. Consider checking the contents of node_modules/ffmpeg-binaries contents. Why is there no bin/ffmpeg? For example, f you installed modules on Windows and deployed them to AWS, it's possible that there's no Linux binary. I'd suggest to try ffmpeg-static instead.